# How can I run a single endpoint multiple times?

Tags: postman

I have a Collection that has three endpoints. The first one creates an asset, the second one adds a file to the asset, and the third one lists all the assets.

How can I run the second one, the one that adds a file to the asset, more than once per each iteration of the Runner?

I'd like the test to create an asset and add multiple files to it for each iteration.

Any suggestions? I know I can duplicate the endpoint, but I was wondering if there was a programmatic way to do it.

Comment: Check out this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman, it has some iterable functionality. Otherwise, if you're just using postman, you might only be able to copy and paste the request multiple times in the Test Run Json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, there is no straight forward solution using Postman, to configure several hits for the same request within a folder/collection.

Nevertheless, you can write some code in [Pre-request script](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/pre_request_scripts) section, by adding a counter with number of hits you want and call `postman.setNextRequest("request_name")` method (*read more about it from [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/workflows)*) with you current request.

Out of Postman app scope, you can export your collection (as **JSON** file) and write some javascript code using `newman` which is a Command-line companion utility for Postman (*more about newman from [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman)*) which gets a `run` method with a lot of iteration count and data options that would help you (for example, putting your second request in folder and iterates through it).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

1. Create 2 environment variables:

   - *"Counter"* (Number of times you want the request to run)
   - *"RequestNumber"*  = 1 (To track the current request number)
2. Add this code to the test section of the request you want to run multiple times:

   ```
   const counter = pm.environment.get("Counter");
   const requestNumber = pm.environment.get("RequestNumber") || 1;
   if (requestNumber < counter) {
       postman.setNextRequest("RequestName");
       requestNumber ++;
       pm.environment.set("RequestNumber", requestNumber);
   }
   else {
       pm.environment.set("RequestNumber", 1);
   }
   ```

Comment: I think you meant to use a while loop instead of an if statement

Comment: also `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`, you cant increment a constant, perhaps you meant `let`

Comment: @kbluue `while` loop is not suitable for this particular case since `postman.setNextRequest()` does not send request, but moves runner to request with provided name. `while` would work just fine if we used `pm.sendRequest()`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `postman.setNextRequest()`, a bit cleaner way to hit the same endpoint is to use `pm.sendRequest()`.

In *Test* or *Pre-request Script*, you can create a *request object* that would describe the request you want to send *(URL, HTTP method, headers body, etc.)* and put it in `pm.sendRequest()` *function*.

Consider:

```
const requestObject = {
    url: 'https://postman-echo.com/post',
    method: 'POST',
    header: 'headername1:value1',
    body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: JSON.stringify({ key: "this is json" })
    }
}

pm.sendRequest(requestObject, (err, res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

To run the same request multiple times just put the function in `for`/`for..in`/`for..of`/`forEach` *loop*.

Consider:

```
for(let iteration = 0; iteration < 5; iteration++) {
  pm.sendRequest(requestObject, (err, res) => {
      console.log(res);
  });
}
```

If you want you can modify the `requestObject` inside your *loop*.

Check out the [Postman Documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#pmsendrequest) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Postman Team created a [tutorial](https://www.postman.com/praveendvd-public/workspace/postman-tricks-and-tips/request/8296678-71240756-0d98-4f77-9e40-01ea4e8fe683) for just that.

It consists into adding the following in the Pre-request Script section:

```
pm.variables.set("retryCount",3)
```

Then adding the following in the Tests section:

```
pm.variables.get("retryCounter") === undefined ? 
pm.variables.set('retryCounter', pm.variables.get("retryCount")) : null
retryCount = pm.variables.get("retryCounter");
if (retryCount > 1) {
    pm.variables.set('retryCounter', --retryCount)
    postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName);
}
```

Finally, just run the collection in the collection runner.