# Postman seeding loop

Tags: javascript, postman

I've got request in postman that creates new user profile in database. I would like to create new seeder that would create 10 profiles each time request is run, I've tried doing loops but request runs only one. Could anyone help?

```html
pm.environment.set("repeat", 11);
var currentCount = pm.environment.get("repeat")
if (currentCount > 0){
    currentCount = currentCount -1 ;
    pm.environment.set("repeat", currentCount);
    postman.setNextRequest("Create individual profiles")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [Postman runner](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/intro-to-collection-runs/)? Or [this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61025683/3990896).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to pre-request of the request you want to run multiple times:

```
if (pm.variables.get("repeat")===undefined) pm.variables.set("repeat", 1);
var currentCount = pm.variables.get("repeat")
console.log(currentCount)
if (currentCount!==1){
    currentCount -=1 ; 
    pm.variables.set("repeat", currentCount);
    postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName)
}
```

this will keep sending the request till currentCOunt is 1,

you cannot use setNextRequest in loop as its always the "last one wins"